Paste Image in Multi-line Rich Texarea from Clipboard
How to copy paste image or screenshot in multiline rich text and save in Sharepoint list

Are you doing this directly in SharePoint online list form or from any custom solution like Power Apps / SPFx?

we have used custom coding with js
